# How To Build a Template Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, template-engine

I'll be building this in Google App Engine and I'll be Building it using Python.

What I'd like to do is have a template that holds each section.  With the sections probably being header, sidebar, content and footer.

The way I would build it is so that I can call page.header(arg) and it will load the header that the arg specifies.

I know there are a lot of frameworks, but I want to try and build a website based on the MVC idea my self.  I figure it will probably take 6 months or more to build, but at least I'll learn something along the way.

What else do I need to think about building a template engine?

Comment: Check Nick Johnson's discussion of template engines on app engine [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Webapps-on-App-Engine-part-4-Templating).

Comment: David, that whole series looks awesome to read.  It's doing almost exactly what I want to do!

Comment: I use Cheetah at work for a custom configuration system we build and it works great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out [Webpy](https://github.com/webpy/webpy) sources;
webpy [templating](http://webpy.org/tutorial3.en#templating) uses a syntax similar to yours, calling the views with something like:

```
name = 'Bob'    
return render.index(name)
```

where `index` is the templating file to render.

Have a look to [templating.py](https://github.com/webpy/webpy/blob/master/web/template.py) specifically.